# Excel sumifs until a new value in column

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have some data that looks like:

```
Day       Result 
1-Nov       1 
            0
            1
2-Nov       1
3-Nov       0
            0
4-Nov       1
```

There are other columns with data. I only have the date once as the data is displayed graphically in a time series.

Now I'd like to setup a summary table that aggregates each day. I cannot use `sumifs`  because the date is only in the data once.

How could I write a calculation such that excel sees a2 has a value so sums b2,b3,...bi until ai has a value.

Preferably not vba, never learned it and want to do this in excel rather than R or Python.

EDIT:

I am specifically looking at how to do calculations on the result column grouped by each date. Blank cells should be considered the same date. So when excel sees 1-Nov it then does a calculation (i've said sum but any we can extend to) on 1,0,1 and then stops and a new calculation is done for Nov-2.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, instead of using a table like this:

```
Day     Result
01/nov  1
        0
        1
02/nov  1
03/nov  0
        0
04/nov  1
```

You should populate the "Day" column and use a pivot table to summarize the results.

I.e.:

```
Day     Result
01/nov  1
01/nov  0
01/nov  1
02/nov  1
03/nov  0
03/nov  0
04/nov  1
```

And the pivot table:

[image]

Comment: Sorry that doesn't help as that is not what I'm trying to achieve. Note I choose sumif arbitrarily, I would like a method that is extendable for other calculations too.

Comment: Maybe you can use a pivot table with a ["Calculated Field/Item"](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/calculated-field-item.html) and refresh the table everytime you insert a new data in your table...

Comment: Sorry that is not what I am asking to do. Im specifically trying to do something like a sumif where excel stops when it finds a new value in the a column. This is certainly doable in vba, if not normally.

Comment: I think you should rewrite your question, since you mention " I'd like to setup a summary table that aggregates each day" and "Preferably not vba". You never mentioned that the "sumif" needs to "stops when it finds a new value in the a column". (And btw, you can filter the info in the pivot table to show only the slice of days you want using rules like "day > 01/nov and day < 06/nov")

Comment: The reason i'm doing it this way is because each date is a tick on my time series chart and repeating dates would repeat values on the chart. There may be an option to only show each unique date once though - although im now interested in seeing if what ive asked is doable.